# more than one authorization mode for APIs (Basic and OAuth)

Tags: c#, azure, oauth, authorization, azure-api-management

I have one common Azure API where i have to implement two ways of authorization.

Basic
OAuthToken.

Some clients use only basic and some use oauth.

What is the best way to proceed and best place to put this logic.

Considering tomorrow some other client come with some other authentication logic.I mean should I separate API based on authentication mode or have both in single API?

I have APIM, is there a easy way to achieve this? Currently I have set basic in policy but I am thinking it would overload so thinking if I should make a "Version 2" of the Version 1 API and then  set oAuth there?

Comment: I see you are already using APIM, surely that's the best way to go?

Comment: @MickyD: Thank you, I use policy where I have mentioned basic. Is it ok to use one more condition to do oauth? How do I do that toggling based on a flag

Comment: @MickyD: Can you please provide me a sample toggle logical statement to switch based on a flag value (boolean) in policy. Also why do you say APIm is the best place?

Comment: Because the nice thing about APIM is that security such as authentication can be added to an API after the fact purely in APIM in many cases without requiring changes to the original API code.  I can't help with the other questions sadly

Comment: No problem good sir

Answer (score 0):

That would depend on how you decide what auth method to apply. You could have different products with different policies enforcing different auth methods. These products would include same API and you'll direct users to use subscription keys for a product that enforces auth method they're interested in.

If auth method is selected by user explicitly, then you can have a choose policy in your API to make a decision. For example, check whether Authorization header starts with "Basic" and if it does - apply basic auth, otherwise use validate-jwt for example.

Comment: Thank you, how to implement a new API for to choose a particular authentication from policy? Well some of my universities share me the client credentials for me to pass it to them for token generation while accessing their api and hence I want to have this OAuth authorization, while some universities just need username and password which is basic authorization which is already set. I dont know how to make it for autho.